# Missing message body and image attachment in MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In my app, I have a `button` that when pressed, will present an `MFMailComposeViewController` that is pre-populated with a subject, message body, and a jpg. However, I am noticing some strange behavior. Often the `MFMailComposeViewController` appears with the message body and image attached, but other times, it will appear without the message body and image attachment, though the subject is always properly presented. I am running my app on `iOS 8`. My code is below. Any suggestions/advice will be much appreciated.

```
- (void)emailButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [picker setSubject:@"My Subject"];

    [picker setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Message Body"] isHTML:YES];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image, 1.0);
    NSString *fileName = @"myFileName";
    fileName = [fileName stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"jpeg"];
    [picker addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:fileName];

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not found a solution to this.

Comment: I found that, it is working properly with Xcode 6 Beta 2

Comment: The erroneous behavior appears sporadically for me on iPhone 5S running iOS 8.